# Error in updating appointment

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to add more required attendees. But i am running up with errors and the code is -2146233087.

```
activityparty activityParty = new activityparty();         
activityParty.partyid = new Lookup();            
activityParty.partyid.Value = contact.contactid.Value;     
appointment.requiredattendees = new activityparty[] { activityParty };   
service.Update(appointment);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi atlast i found the issue, i missed the type of entity and tats the problem. But it is simply throwing error as exception without telling that and after adding type it is fixed.

```
activityparty activityParty = new activityparty();         
activityParty.partyid = new Lookup();            
activityParty.partyid.Value = contact.contactid.Value;     
**activityParty.partyid.type = "contact";**
appointment.requiredattendees = new activityparty[] { activityParty };   
service.Update(appointment);
```